# Unable to start Zookeeper server while setting up Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

```
adeeshwar@adeeshwar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/kafka_2.11-1.1.0$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

adeeshwar@adeeshwar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/kafka_2.11-1.1.0$
```

please help how can i start the zookeeper server so that i can start kafka

I'm newwbie to Apache kafka and Flink so I'm just trying and testing things.

**I'm following the instructions on these links**
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart

**hands on Kafka**

https://data-artisans.com/blog/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to

Comment: Can you share more information like how many nodes you are trying to start and also what are the zookeeper configurations you have set in zookeeper.properties. Also, it would be helpful if you could provide error logs that occurs while trying to start zookeeper.

Comment: Zookeeper should start out of the box with the defaults. There should also be logs generated when you run the start command

Comment: @ Daniccan VP i'm trying to run it on my local machine so only one node. I downloaded kafka from this link      https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/1.1.0/kafka_2.11-1.1.0.tgz   untar it in my home directory      and following the steps as written in quickstart doccumentation. The problem is that i'm not receiving any error logs. Its just return me the prompt on terminal.

Comment: @ cricket_007 Actually it generated the logs the first time. But my machine accidentally turned off. And now when I'm starting zookeper server its just returning me an empty prompt. I also checked if any instance is already running but no instance is running already.

Comment: Can anyone tell what i'm doing wrong?